# How do I print out a different result based on value of a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if you could use a string concatenation to call a variable, or even name variable. I am attempting to output different text depending on what parameter is passed in a function.

```js
function myFunction(direction) {
  var previousElement = "Previous Element";
  var nextElement = "Next Element";
  console.log(direction+Element);
  //I want it to print "Previous Element" or "Next Element" depending on what the direction is.
}

myFunction('previous');
```

Comment: Why are you asking about string concatenation?  Your example is not doing any concatenation.

Comment: What is `Element` in your example?  It is never defined anywhere.

Comment: @RJM - They want to access the next or previous element where `direction` is the variable and "Element" is the appended string to form a dynamic variable so that it returns the value of either `previousElement` or `nextElement`.

Comment: That's not what the code was doing.

Comment: @RJM - That is the point. It is pseudo-code. They are asking if it is possible and are representing it the best way they know how.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way would be to wrap the directions as an object:

```js
function myFunction(direction) {
    var element = {
        "previous": "Previous Element",
        "next": "Next Element"
    };
    return direction in element ? element[direction] : false;
}

myFunction('previous');

//I want it to print "Previous Element" or "Next Element" depending on what the direction is.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using an object to hold it, and use the variable to access the property with bracket notation.

```js
var msgs = {
   "previous" : "Previous Element",
   "next" : "Next Element"
};

function myFunction(direction) {
  console.log(msgs[direction]);
}

myFunction('previous');
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you're going to have to use `eval` or some other flavour essentially doing the same thing.

```js
function myFunction(direction) {
  var previousElement = "Previous Element";
  var nextElement = "Next Element";
  
  // Construct an actual call to previousElement or nextElement, not a string
  var variable = eval(direction + "Element");
  
  console.log(variable);
}

myFunction('previous');

//I want it to print "Previous Element" or "Next Element" depending on what the direction is.
```

This of course [isn't the safest or smartest thing to do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!), but it is what you're asking and returns the right result.

Answer (score -1):

Use `console.log(direction + "Element")` in your function.

- Concatenates the two strings. You wrote your code wrong as you are trying to access a non existent array element.
- Direction is not an array. It is a string.